# Tag synonyms standard-visitor-visa and standard-visitor-visas

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We seem to have two separate tags:

- standard-visitor-visa - 85 followers
- standard-visitor-visas - 569 followers

Should we set one of them as a synonym for the other?

Comment: Hm... seems this is already the case. I wonder why this wasn't obvious when I looked initially. I'm deleting the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have undeleted your question. Even though the synonym already existed, I looked into the tags and managed to clean-up and merge them so that they now appear as one. Therefore, I am answering here to say thanks for bringing this up, and keep up the good work.

Comment: No problem :) Thanks for cleaning things up.